# Placeholders for missing images

Tags: image, placeholder

If a data source doesn't contain images for certain items, what is the best way to indicate that the image used is a placeholder image?

The type of placeholder image would probably alter dependant on the type of image that should be there. For example if its a missing image of a person then a silhouetted image of a person would probably be used. But what if its a generic image whereby I don't want to indicate the type of image that's missing, only that this particular item doesn't have its own image.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT/ADDITION**

Ok lets get into specifics then. Lets assume a placeholder is needed. it has to be a generic placeholder i.e. no human silhouette or identicon or file type. Is the best solution a variation on the **flat grey mountain and sun icon?** I believe it is but what are peoples thoughts on this?

Comment: For serious answers see below but for a bit of fun you could always consider [Fill Murray](http://www.fillmurray.com/)

Comment: @CharlesWesley I will be considering that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it depends on content too much to give a single answer.

> what is the best way to indicate that the image used is a placeholder image?

Generally, you want it to be easy to tell **the placeholder** from **the real thing**. So if the expected image is a photo, do not use a photographic image as a placeholder, but rather an icon.

Always make sure that the placeholder **matches the style and colors of the system**, visually showing that this piece of graphic is a part of the program controls, not a part of the user contents, or perhaps just leave the space empty.

Some variations:

- **Layout** does not necessarily require a placeholder. Not finding a good example right now, so this menu will have to do:

  [image]
- **Containers** can be used so that it does not matter whether there is an image inside or not (Empty folder below)
- **Icons**: could be used, depending on the situation, just like the silhouette you mention, or the Empty Image below:

  [image]

### Edit/Addition (see question)

If the image that needs a placeholder is the type of image that actually *could be* The Sun and the Mountain, then yes, using that metaphor would work.

If the image, when existing, rather would be a picture of a tool (a hammer), a shape (a polygon, a border, a rounded corner), an organism (an amoeba), then pick another metaphor accordingly.

If you really need a placeholder image/icon for your "generic image", then the job starts in finding that metaphor, and many systems find The Sun and the Mountain appropriate.

Comment: Good points. Agree with everything here. ive updated my question getting into specifics of the icon to use. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Amending my answer.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[Identicons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon), as shown in the attached image above, are good options as the placeholder for missing images.

Advantages:

- Does not indicate the type of image that's missing, only that this particular item doesn't have its own image.
- [Identicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) will prevent user grouping the items with products with the same placeholder images. See below attached image.

[image]

At first glanced, using same placeholder images, users might group them as similar product.

Comment: You know it wouldn't hurt to actually mention the word ["identicon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon)...

Comment: Thanks Tobias, Identicon that's the word. I've been scratching my head over what does that call.

Comment: You're welcome - I found it either on http://gravatar.com or somewhere on http://meta.stackoverflow.com... Anyway, more information on it is at http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/blogger/wp_identicon/

Comment: (sidenote: [If you're more into unicorns...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns))

Comment: (...and animations: http://chaostangent.com/2009/09/50-frames-of-life/ - I'll stop here...)

Comment: thanks for the response @SimonTeo , ive made an edit to my post, what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

In that case, you might just want to use a plain grey box. The sun and mountain suggest a photo of a landscape if you ask me. Just my thoughts.

Comment: I would think that the images still take some time to load, resp. that some error is preventing the images from loading.

Answer (score 2):

In @SimonTeo's case, a much better solution in my opinion is to abbreviate the name/username combined with different background-colors.

If someone's called "Name Namely":

[image]